# Mysql select query for dynamically convert rows to column not working when passing variable while passing static value worked

Tags: php, mysqli

I have written mysql query to convert rows to column dynamically. This query works fine when I am sending static value to prn. But when I am taking input from $prn I am getting out put as empty array.
Following is the code-

```
 $prn=$_GET['prn'];
 echo 'prn:'.$prn;

 $sql = "SET @sql = NULL;
        SELECT
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
              'GROUP_CONCAT(IF(finding_field = ''',
              finding_field,
              ''',finding_value, NULL)) AS ',
              finding_field
            )
          ) INTO @sql
        FROM cpc_specific_finding;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT finding_no
                            , ', @sql, ' 
                           FROM cpc_specific_finding 
                           where prn='$prn' 
                           GROUP BY finding_no');

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";

 $mydata = array();
 if (mysqli_multi_query($localCon,$sql)){
  do{       
    if ($result= mysqli_store_result($localCon)) {

      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $mydata[] = $row;            
        }         
      mysqli_free_result($result);
      }
    }    
  while (mysqli_next_result($localCon));
 }

 echo json_encode($mydata);
```

I have tried with writing prn='".$prn."' which doesn't worked.

Comment: Before even trying this, you should take a look at http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection. What you're to do right now is really unsafe and your database could be hacked in a few seconds. Learn about prepared statements and how to use them (its really easy, just look at the website linked) :)

Comment: Thanks.. but that doesn't solved my question.

Comment: It does. If you would take a look at how prepared statements works, you'll see that their working with placeholders in the query, where you can bind a variable to this placeholder. So finally, if you would use prepared statement, there's no need to solve your problem here, because it won't exist anymore. I don't see any reason why I should try to find the error in this code, when you're going to change the code anyways (if you're really gonna use prep. statements...)

Comment: Actually problem remains here with bind_param(). I am getting 'Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in' error on bind_param() line.

Comment: var_dump($sql); after prepare statement returning bool(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer :D. I am posting answer if anyone found helpful.

In 3rd query value for prn was passing along with '' so removed quotes, it should like.

```
where prn=$prn
```

and it worked.

Comment: I know - Its still not save.